# Share to Facebook from Android

Tags: c#, android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I have problem share to facebook from android use unity C#.

When I try, when debug, it's always need user access token to share, and when share it's just share to tester and admin.

When I try on device it's just show "this application will be access to your email ..." and after that nothing happened.

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Facebook;

public class PTShare : MonoBehaviour {
    private string lastResponse = "";
    public OTSprite shareBtn;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Awake () {
        CallFBInit ();
    }

    void Start () {

        shareBtn = GameObject.Find ("share").GetComponent<OTSprite>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () { 
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            if(OT.Over(shareBtn)) {
                FB.Login("email,publish_actions", LoginCallback); 

                CallFBFeed();  
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerator GetAppAccessToken() {
        //Debug.Log("asking FB for App AccessToken");
        string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_ id={0}&client_secret={1}",
                                   "1443575049241638",
                                   "efde01d85ba62e4d81708b4189419d5c");

        WWW fbRequest = new WWW(url);

        // Wait for download to complete
        yield return fbRequest;

        string accessToken = fbRequest.text;
        Debug.Log("got token: " + accessToken);
        accessToken = accessToken.Substring(accessToken.IndexOf("=") + 1);
        Debug.Log("trimmed token: " + accessToken);

        //FB.UserId = accessToken;

        return true;
    }

    public string FeedToId = "";
    public string FeedLink = "http://gambrenggames.com/game-detail/junes-potion/2";
    public string FeedLinkName = "June's Potion";
    public string FeedLinkCaption = "I play June's Potion friends! Can you play it?";
    public string FeedLinkDescription = "";
    public string FeedPicture = "http://gambrenggames.com/website/images/game-icon/05540225032014.png";
    public string FeedMediaSource = "";
    public string FeedActionName = "";
    public string FeedActionLink = "";
    public string FeedReference = "";
    public bool IncludeFeedProperties = false;
    private Dictionary<string, string[]> FeedProperties = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

    private void CallFBFeed()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string[]> feedProperties = null;
        if (IncludeFeedProperties)
        {
            feedProperties = FeedProperties;
        }
        FB.Feed(
            toId: FeedToId,
            link: FeedLink,
            linkName: FeedLinkName,
            linkCaption: FeedLinkCaption,
            linkDescription: FeedLinkDescription,
            picture: FeedPicture,
            mediaSource: FeedMediaSource,
            actionName: FeedActionName,
            actionLink: FeedActionLink,
            reference: FeedReference,
            properties: feedProperties,
            callback: Callback
            );
    }

    private Texture2D lastResponseTexture;
    public string ApiQuery = "";

    void Callback(FBResult result)
    {
        lastResponseTexture = null;
        // Some platforms return the empty string instead of null.
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
            lastResponse = "Error Response:\n" + result.Error;
        else if (!ApiQuery.Contains("/picture"))
            lastResponse = "Success Response:\n" + result.Text;
        else
        {
            lastResponseTexture = result.Texture;
            lastResponse = "Success Response:\n";
        }
    }

    private bool isInit = false;

    private void CallFBInit()
    {
        FB.Init(OnInitComplete, OnHideUnity);
    }

    private void OnInitComplete()
    {
        Debug.Log("FB.Init completed: Is user logged in? " + FB.IsLoggedIn);
        isInit = true;
    }

    private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
    {
        Debug.Log("Is game showing? " + isGameShown);
    }

    private void CallFBLogin()
    {
        FB.Login("email,publish_actions", LoginCallback);
    }

    void LoginCallback(FBResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error != null)
            lastResponse = "Error Response:\n" + result.Error;
        else if (!FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            lastResponse = "Login cancelled by Player";
        }
        else
        {
            lastResponse = "Login was successful!";
        }
    }

    private void CallFBLogout()
    {
        FB.Logout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FB.Login is async method and FB.Feed (maybe?) requires Login.

So try call CallFBFeed(); inside  LoginCallback method. Like that:

```
 void Update () { 
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                if(OT.Over(shareBtn)) {
                 if (FB.IsLoggedIn)
                   {
                      CallFBFeed();  
                   } 
                   else 
                   {
                     FB.Login("email,publish_actions", LoginCallback); 
                   }                      
                }
            }
         }

void LoginCallback(FBResult result)
    {
        if (result.Error != null)
            lastResponse = "Error Response:\n" + result.Error;
        else if (!FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            lastResponse = "Login cancelled by Player";
        }
        else
        {
            lastResponse = "Login was successful!";
CallFBFeed();  
        }
    }
```

But it can be problem with android device (i had "magic" with fb login on some old devices) or settings and your code is ok